# Add downloaded components to existing library in Altium?

Tags: components, altium, library

I have just started using Altium as a student after using Eagle for a lot of years.

I download part libraries from sites like Ultra Librarian and can use the supplied script to generate a library with symbol, footprint and 3D body, I can then compile so I can use it in a design.

But this is going to end up with me having hundreds and libraries with just one part in each. How can I create one library and import the downloaded files from Ultra Libary (and others) into that library? Bearing in mind that I have no scripting experience.

Basically, I want to end up with one library for say one brand of MCUs, comm transceivers, connectors etc much like in eagle.

Comment: https://discord.me/altium - then press join server. You may need to create an account.

Comment: Thanks, very useful, but do you know the answer to my question? I have downloaded and installed that library and it doesn't include most of the components I require. It'll be quicker for me to create download the files from a website and add them to an existing library than waiting for someone to add a part for me.

Comment: I did mean for you to get involved in that forum because it is quite active but, the libraries are a bonus @b - it's probably the best place to get advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the various individual libraries in Altium.
- Open the your new target library.
- Right-click on the component, in the component panel list, that you want to include in your new library, and select 'Copy'.
- Right-click in your new library and select 'Paste' in the component list.

This works for both Schematic and PCB libraries.

Going from Eagle to *fAultium* is a big jump.  Read the docs.  Join the **Official** Altium forum ( https://forum.live.altium.com ).